# Dependency between classes without explicit import

Tags: java, import, dependencies

Let's consider this simple class hierarchy in Java:

class A:

```
package a;

import b.B;

public class A {
    public B a() {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

class B:

```
package b;

public class B {
    public void b() {
        System.out.println("B!");
    }
}
```

class Main:

```
import a.A;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.a().b();
    }
}
```

As can be seen, there is only a direct import of `A` from class `Main`. However, we are calling the method `b` returned from `A.a()`. 
My questions is, although we don't have a direct import dependency between `Main` and `B`, are they still considered directly dependent? for example, when I'm analysing dependencies between classes?

Comment: This is a very interesting question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is a direct dependency. You just don't have to state it to the compiler, because it can look at the method signature that it returns a `B` and will resolve the class for you.

If the compiler cannot find `B` (or the method you want to call on it), you will get a compile-time error about a missing class.

At run-time, when you load a class, it also loads all classes referred to in method signatures (and fails if those cannot be found).

Also note that the `import` statements themselves are just for the compiler. They have no effect on the resulting class file. That means if you import ten classes that you are then not using, those will not become dependencies (the compiler will still complain about them missing in your import section, but they won't be loaded at runtime).

Answer (score 2):

When compiled, the compiler links up the dependencies.

This means that, because `a.A` is used, and imported, the imports from `a.A` are also added to the compilation (or linking, IIRC).

As of such, if you look at the resulting `.class` file, you'll see that it imports `b.B`.

So to answer your question: At the java level, they are indirectly dependent. after compilation - directly dependent.

(I may be wrong about this, but this is my understanding of it. If someone knows better, by all means correct me :D)